# Is it normal for Elastic Beanstak operations to take forever?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

Every time I deploy, reboot, or change a configuration setting on EB, the change takes several minutes to take effect, during which time my environment's status is "Updating" and I can't do anything. I keep finding myself thinking, "This can't be how it is for everyone."

Is it normal for EB to be this slow or is there a chance it's just me and I can do something to make it faster?

Comment: I don't use EB much but I have certainly felt the same way when waiting for  EC2 and RDS changes.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're correct... it isn't that way for everyone.

Today (2015-09-23) being an exception.

> **AWS Elastic Beanstalk (N. Virginia)**
>
> **[RESOLVED] Increased API error rates and provisioning latencies**
>
> 8:35 AM PDT We can confirm increased API error rates as well as provisioning and scaling latencies for some environments in the US-EAST-1 Region.
>
> 11:15 AM PDT Between 6:05 AM and 9:16 AM PDT, customers experienced elevated API error rates and delays in environment creation and deployment operations in the US-EAST-1 Region. The service is operating normally.
>
> — http://status.aws.amazon.com